# Java, searching two ArrayLists doesn't work

Tags: java, arraylist

I am freaked out about the following code and surprised that it didn't work. Here I want to compare two ArrayLists the way I want as in below. So I can't get match for "Green" just because it is added to the ww list with a space contained " Green" even I used trim() but still doesn't work. 
Thanks you very much for your expertise to help me with this strange error.

```
ArrayList<String> ww = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<String> mm = new ArrayList();
ww.add("Orange");
ww.add(" Green".trim());
mm.add("Orange");
mm.add("Green");

for ( String x:ww){
        for ( y:mm){
            if (x==y){
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
    }
```

After running:

```
Orange
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare two strings using `==` for value equality. `==` is only for reference equality. Revise your if-condition to be:

```
if(x.equals(y))
```

Specifically, while "Orange" exists in the constant pool (same reference for both cases of it being used), two instances of "Green" exist--one in the constant pool. and one returned by `String#trim()`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but can you please tell me why it works for Orange but not for Green?

Comment: @jesy2013: Because the result of `" Green".trim()` isn't a reference to the same string as `"Green"`... whereas interning means that both `"Orange"` occurrences refer to the same string.

Comment: @jesy2013 If you assing a string using `"Orange"` the JVM will cache it internally so it doesn't has to create an new instance if you assign another string with `"Orange"`. This means both string variables reference to the same object. If you call `" Green".trim()` a completely new instance of a string containing `"Green"` will be created and assigned to your variable. So the list `ww` contains a string with `"Green"` that is not the same object as in the list `mm` even if both strings contain the same "data".